# Load same results back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page tha displays results. The results are loaded into a content div via an ajax request on (document).ready. The results can be filtered using a form. On $(#filter_form).submit() the ajax request is made and the content div is populated with the filtered results.Up to here all is well.

Clicking a result will load the results details in a new page, non ajax load. On clicking the back button we go back to the results page,the form checkboxes are still checked, but the filters are no longer applied to the results. Obviously on document.ready the first, non filtered, ajax request is made and the non filtered results are loaded.

My initial idea was on page ready to check if any of the form elements are checked, and if they were, to submit the form. Problem is I have no idea how to make this work.

My script to load the filtered results is this:

```
$('#filter_form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

       $.ajax({
                url: '<?=base_url().'catalog/show_listings/?';?>'+queryString,
                type:'GET',
                data: $('form#filter_form').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(listings){
                        $('#result_container').html(listings);
                    } // End of success function of ajax form       
         }); // End of ajax call
    });
```

I managed to figure out how to check if any form elements are active :

```
 var validate= false;

    $('#requestfilter_from').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '' || $(this).attr('checked'))
            validate = true;
    });
```

I just have no idea how to combine the two. I tried running the ajax request in the second script (dont have that script to post anymore) but it didnt provide any results.

Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problems boils down to saving the "state" of the filters (keeping track of which ones are checked even if the user leaves the page).

You can easily do this by appending query parameters to the url. For instance, if someone selects a filter `checkbox1`, you can append `&checkbox1=true` to the url. This way, even
when user leaves the page and hits back button, you will have `&checkbox1=true` in the url.

Now, you need to modify the initial loading of data to take query parameters into account.
So don't load all the data at the start. Instead, parse query parameter, prepare the url based on filters found in the query params and then fire the ajax query which loads initial data.

Here are the steps -

1. On selection of a filter, append query parameter to url.
2. On `$(document).ready`, parse query parameter, and

   - Make sure you update the input boxes, so they reflect the state of the filters.
     For e.g, if `&checkbox1=true` was found in the url, make sure `input[name=checkbox1]` is checked.
   - Fire the initial ajax query with filter parameters

This comes with a bonus. Now, your users can also pass around the url with selected filters.

PS: Look into `jQuery.param.querystring`

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed! Question, do I parse through the checkboxes and check if they are checked or not and then add or subtract them from an array which I then use param to create querystring? Or is there a way to param the whole form in one go on change of any checkbox, without having to add and subtract if boxes are checked or not?

Comment: No. You will never need to parse through the form. Just update the query param whenever something is checked. When unchecked, parse the query param and remove the `&key=value` from it. All ajax requests are made by parsing the query param and not the `form`. Query param is your single-source of truth and everything else updates it or reads from it.

Comment: I am way out of my comfort zone here. I tried this :

    $('form#filter_form input').change(function(){

   alert($.param('#form.fiter_form'));

  });
But it return the same string regardless of the boxes checked :
0=f&1=o&2=r&3=m&4=%23&5=f&6=i&7=l&8=t&9=e&10=r&11=_&12=f&13=o&14=r&15=m

Comment: This : 

var string = $('form#filter_form').serialize();

Gives me a string. COuld this be used?

Comment: `.serialize()` should get you form data to be sent (look out for encoding). For reading the query string, quick google search leads me to this http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html. I'm sure there must be a plugin as well to get the query string. Either should do.

Comment: Also, `jQuery.param` needs json object to be serialized. You are passing the string id, and hence it doesn't work. Try form.serialize and let me know.